# How to show battery status in Zsh prompt

Tags: command-prompt, zsh

I think the answer is quite self explanatory.

I've been looking around for a software that already does this but I haven't had any luck. It's either not done in Zsh, or it's for another app, for example tmux. Point is I haven't been able to find it.

So my question is, is there already a pre-made script that somebody did that does this? If there is, could you please share a link to it.

If there isn't, what should I look into to making this script? I'm a newbie at Zsh scripting so bear that in mind.

The idea is that it outputs something along the lines of `67%`. You get the point. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very-very simple solution:

```
setopt promptsubst
PROMPT='$(acpi | grep -o "[0-9]*%)% '
```

Comment: This won’t work: it will set prompt once and be done. Use single quotes and `setopt promptsubst`.

Answer (score 8):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129404/1084945) doesn't work on Mac OS X (no `apci`).

I've taken bits of [Steve Losh's zsh prompt](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/#my-right-prompt-battery-capacity) in my prompt. It's not exactly what you're after - the arrows `▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸▸` show the current battery state, and change color when the battery gets low. This method uses a Python script, which for completeness I'll add below. Here's a screenshot of my prompt in action:

[image: My zsh prompt]

Another method for OS X is presented [on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/osxterminal/comments/1aum9n/show_your_battery_percentage_and_charging_status/), using another short script:

```
ioreg -n AppleSmartBattery -r | awk '$1~/Capacity/{c[$1]=$3} END{OFMT="%.2f%%"; max=c["\"MaxCapacity\""]; print (max>0? 100*c["\"CurrentCapacity\""]/max: "?")}'
ioreg -n AppleSmartBattery -r | awk '$1~/ExternalConnected/{gsub("Yes", "+");gsub("No", "%"); print substr($0, length, 1)}'
```

Assuming this script is saved in `~/bin/battery.sh`:

```
function battery {
    ~/bin/battery.sh
}
setopt promptsubst
PROMPT='$(battery) $'
```

which looks like this:

[image: Reddit-based battery charge.]

---

To use Steve Losh's script, save the script somewhere, and use it in the `battery()` function above.

#### The battery-charge Python script for OS X

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=UTF-8

import math, subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["ioreg", "-rc", "AppleSmartBattery"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]

o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'MaxCapacity' in l][0]
o_cur = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'CurrentCapacity' in l][0]

b_max = float(o_max.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())
b_cur = float(o_cur.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())

charge = b_cur / b_max
charge_threshold = int(math.ceil(10 * charge))

# Output

total_slots, slots = 10, []
filled = int(math.ceil(charge_threshold * (total_slots / 10.0))) * u'▸'
empty = (total_slots - len(filled)) * u'▹'

out = (filled + empty).encode('utf-8')
import sys

color_green = '%{[32m%}'
color_yellow = '%{[1;33m%}'
color_red = '%{[31m%}'
color_reset = '%{[00m%}'
color_out = (
    color_green if len(filled) > 6
    else color_yellow if len(filled) > 4
    else color_red
)

out = color_out + out + color_reset
sys.stdout.write(out)
```

Comment: Thanks! While it doesn't count because I'm on Linux and this is for the Mac, it is a very well thought out and made answer. Voted useful. :)

Answer (score 5):

Even though this thread is quite old, I thought I post my version here, too:

I used the basic concept of [steve losh's](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/) battery prompt but altered it in the first place to not use python but shell, which is far quicker and also changed the battery path to my arch linux distro. Additionally I added a green bold '+' at the end if my laptop is charging:
[image: This is how my prompt looks with the battery status]

my battery function looks as follows:

```sh
    function battery_charge {
      b_now=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now)
      b_full=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full)
      b_status=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)
      # I am displaying 10 chars -> charge is in {0..9}
      charge=$(expr $(expr $b_now \* 10) / $b_full)

      # choose the color according the charge or if we are charging then always green
      if [[ charge -gt 5 || "Charging" == $b_status ]]; then
        echo -n "%{$fg[green]%}"
      elif [[ charge -gt 2 ]]; then
        echo -n "%{$fg[yellow]%}"
      else
        echo -n "%{$fg[red]%}"
      fi

      # display charge * '▸' and (10 - charge) * '▹'
      i=0;
      while [[ i -lt $charge ]]
      do
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
        echo -n "▸"
      done
      while [[ i -lt 10 ]]
      do
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
        echo -n "▹"
      done

      # display a plus if we are charging
      if [[ "Charging" == $b_status ]]; then
        echo -n "%{$fg_bold[green]%} +"
      fi
      # and reset the color
      echo -n "%{$reset_color%} "
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version with color and written in ZSH.

In your .zshrc file

```
function battery {
    batprompt.sh
}
setopt promptsubst
PROMPT='$(battery) >'
```

and here is a batprompt.sh script for linux.  You could adapt to other ways of reading the battery data or adapt the acpi version from the earlier post:

```
#!/bin/zsh
# BATDIR is the folder with your battery characteristics
BATDIR="/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0"
max=`cat $BATDIR/charge_full`
current=`cat $BATDIR/charge_now`
percent=$(( 100 * $current / $max ))

color_green="%{^[[32m%}"
color_yellow="%{^[[34m%}"
color_red="%{^[[31m%}"
color_reset="%{^[[00m%}"

if [ $percent -ge 80 ] ; then
    color=$color_green;
elif [ $percent -ge 40 ] ; then
    color=$color_yellow;
else
    color=$color_red;
fi
echo $color$percent$color_reset
```

Be warned that the ^[ you see in the color definitions is an Escape character.  If a cut-and-paste does not work properly you will need to convert the ^[ to an Escape character. In VI/Vim you could delete the characters and then insert control-v followeed by the Escape key.

Comment: On Korora (Fedora) it does not work. It doesn't find `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full` and `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now`

Comment: Ok well...it was in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full` and `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This helpmed me for my mac,

```
pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%" | cut -d% -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Zsh has a build-in plugin called [`battery`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/battery/battery.plugin.zsh) since 2011 which allows to show the battery status. In order to activate the plugin, open `~/.zshrc` in your favourite text editor and add `battery` to the plugin setting:

```sh
plugins=(git battery)
```

Save your changes and reload your Zsh session:

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```

The listed plugins are now active.