# How do I format my zsh prompt based on a condition?

Tags: linux, terminal, command-prompt, zsh, prompt

I'm using the answer given here: [How do zsh ansi colour codes work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159856/how-do-zsh-ansi-colour-codes-work) to format and add color to my zsh prompt.

Is there any way to format the prompt based on some conditions?

For example, if the hostname has the word `PROD` in it, then I'd like my prompt to have a red background. Otherwise, I'd like no background, and bold green text.

Comment: Try to use `if` condition in your `.zsh` file (under your root directory) and `set prompt = '...'`

Comment: If you have a function call in your prompt, ZSH will call that function every time the prompt is drawn. If you use an `if...` to set the prompt, your prompt will be set once (at loading) and won't change afterwards. I'd put a conditional in a function: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125498/how-to-show-battery-status-in-zsh-prompt/16227806#16227806) for an example.

Answer (score 4):

Its easy to do now you can use the conditional substring
This is the syntax `%(condition.ifTrue.ifFalse)`

```
export PROMPT="%(%m==PROD.ifTrue.ifFalse)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `precmd` function that resets your prompt just before it is displayed each time.

```
set_red_prompt_background () {
  if [[ ${(%):-%M} = *PROD* ]]; then
    PS1="%K{red}$PS1%k"
  else
    PS1="%F{green}%B$PS1%f%b"
  fi
}

typeset -a precmd_functions
precmd_functions+=(set_red_prompt_background)
```

This isn't tested, so I'd be surprised if it works as is. But here's how it's intended to work.

- `${:-foo}` is a special type of "parameter" expansion which just expands to the word following the `:-`. Seems useless at first...
- `${(%):-%M}` is the same as above, but has the `(%)` flag to instruct `zsh` to process any prompt escapes found in the expansion. This turns into a fancy way of getting the full host name that would appear in the prompt using the `%M` escape.
- Check if it matches the pattern `*PROD*`, i.e., does the host name contain PROD.
- Take whatever the value of `PS1` is, and wrap it in `%K{red}...%k` to make the background red. Note that this might override any background colors already set in `PS1`.
- Add `set_red_prompt_background` to the list of functions executed prior to displaying the prompt. If you add any functions after this, they could potentially override the color you set here.

Answer (score -3):

Edit .zprofile file in your root Directory, with conditions applied on the specific user logged into.