# How to show battery status to show on extreme right of a ZSH prompt?

Tags: debian, command-prompt, zsh

I saw this [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125498/how-to-show-battery-status-in-zsh-prompt) question to what I need/want. Of the answers given, I liked https://stackoverflow.com/a/34913418/3597669 as this is almost what I want/need.

This is my prompt -

[image: zsh prompt - bigfade theme]

Now the difference between the two are is while the answerer has put the triangles and + in the left-corner, I need it on the right-corner.

The other thing is I do not want the full function to be part of .zshrc itself but something that is a self-contained script which I source into .zshrc and is executed.

Is there a way that both the above can be accomplished ? I am on Debian stretch.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want the full function to be part of .zshrc itself but
>   something that is a self-contained script which I source into .zshrc
>   and is executed.

Of course you can just put the function definition in a script and source it.

> I need it on the right-corner.

To display the output of the `function battery_charge` on the right, add

```
setopt promptsubst
RPROMPT='`battery_charge`'
```

to your script.